# Getting the value of element clicked on in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a series of labels that I would like to retrieve the text from when the user clicks on them.  I thought  the jquery might be doable in Emberjs:

```
$(this).attr('text');
```

This however, doesn't work with Ember.  My component view is this:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  {{#each model as |model|}}
    <li {{action "sendToInput"}} class="label label-default">{{model.name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I would like to retrieve that model.name value via the action "sendToInput".

In my component js file I have tried:

```
actions: {
  sendToInput() {
    $(this.target).attr('text');
  }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
this.innerHTML;
$(this).text();
this.get('text');
$(this).val();
```

I have also opened up the console and dug through this and cannot seem to find where they store the element clicked on.

The documentation doesn't mention this and there's no issue I can find on the Github for ember-cli.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to send the value with the action. See [Action Parameters](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/actions/).

Comment: That was it.  And it makes a lot of sense.  Still getting the hang of Ember

Answer (score 2):

The common way is to pass a model name as an action parameter like this:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  {{#each model as |model|}}
    <li {{action "sendToInput" model.name}} class="label label-default">{{model.name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

and then handle it in the action:

```
actions: {
  sendToInput(name) {
    // do something with name
  }
}
```

But if you still need to access the exact element's html, there is another workaround:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    didInsertElement () {
        this.$().on('click', '.label', function (event) {
            $(this).text();
        })
    }

});
```